# Compose a function to preserve record members

Tags: haskell

I have a record, say `structure`, and a mutator function that transforms that record somehow (for example, by altering a member):

```
 a_mutator :: structure -> structure
```

(The `structure` could be the default configuration of my program. The mutator could be a function that changes that default configuration according to command-line options).

(We can also write an alias:

```
 type Mutator structure = structure -> structure
```

)

Now, I don't want the mutator to change certain members of the structure. For example, the user may not be allowed to change the working mode in the configuration.

The way I will enforce that is by saving those members first, applying the mutator, and then putting back the preserved members:

```
preserving :: Lens' structure member -> (structure -> structure) -> (structure -> structure )
preserving le mutator = \ target -> 
  let 
    previous_value = target ^. le 
    mutated = mutator target 
  in set le previous_value mutated
```

where `(^.)` and `set` are coming from the [lens](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Overview) library.

Now, since the type of `preserving`  can be re-written as

```
preserving :: Lens' structure member -> Mutator structure -> Mutator structure
```

it is plausible to compose partial applications of the `preserving` function:

```
preserving lens1 . preserving lens2
```

with the intention of preserving both the member pointed to by lens1 and the member pointed to by lens2. The question is, does this work? That is, `preserving` applications "compose" this way? If so, how can I build some kind of proof of it? And if they don't compose, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to use the lens library to accomplish your purpose, in my opinion. It is potentially inefficient and can open up "security holes" if new "sensitive" fields are added to the structure without updating the `preserving` call(s). Instead of enumerating the things the mutator must *preserve*, you should enumerate the things it may *change*. So

```
mutateMemberWith :: (forall structure .
                  Structure -- Input
               -> structure -- Copy of input
               -> Lens' structure Member
               -> structure)
           -> Structure
           -> Structure
mutateMemberWith f s = f s s appropriateLens
```

The function passed in is not allowed to care what type it produces, so it can only produce it by modifying the input using the given lens.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is "Structure" in uppercase? And what is a sensible name for "f"? Is it some kind of permission?

Comment: @dsign, `Structure` in uppercase is the actual record type, which the function is free to inspect. `f` is the mutator. The lens passed to it is the permission/capability. If you want, you can limit the function still further by not letting it inspect the structure freely but rather giving it some `Getter`s. You can also wrap up the access lens(es) in one or more classes--see `Control.Lens.TH` for some "classy" tools and ideas.